# Sencha Touch - build completed but app doesn't work

Tags: build, sencha-touch-2, production

I've developed an app with sencha touch 2.3.1, in development mode all runs fine. When I run from command line "sencha app build production" everything looks good, not even a single warning is given.

When I try to run the app I see the loading screen and immediately see this message:

```
     Error evaluating http://somepath.com/app.js with message: TypeError: Cannot call method 'getController' of undefined
```

I've checked three times all dependencies, every view has its required views in the requires part. I've addedd all requires that came to my ming, also in controller classes, everywhere but it didn't fix the problem. My application use the getController method in a couple of places in views and in controllers, e.g.

```
    var controller1 = MyApp.app.getController('Controller1');   
    var variable = controller1.... etc etc;
```

in development mode all works fine.
Do you have any insight please?

Comment: Have you tried "sencha app build testing" to see if that works? Also, when in development, do you see any warnings in your browser console?

Comment: Yes, I see a couple of this warnings: " [WARN][Anonymous] [Ext.Loader] Synchronously loading 'MyApp.view.SomeView'; consider adding 'MyApp.view.SomeView' explicitly as a require of the corresponding class " - thrown by Console.js. But all the views have the requires part filled properly, I've checked it thousands of times!

Comment: If the Ext.Loader is complaining about a missing "SomeView" class, then it's missing somewhere important enough to kill your app in production. Just add it to Ext.application({ requires: [...] })